# Big Query Error: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to access the records for the year 2015 from the nyc_yellow cabs table on big query. And I keep running into this error.

Error: Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors.

My Query is:

```
SELECT
  DAYOFWEEK(pickup_datetime) dayofweek,
  INTEGER(100*AVG(trip_distance/((dropoff_datetime-pickup_datetime)/3600000000)))/100 speed,
FROM
  [nyc-tlc:yellow.trips]
  WHERE
  fare_amount/trip_distance between 2
  and 10
  and year(pickup_datetime) = 2015
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

I am using the Free trial.

Comment: what is the question? :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every month you get 1 free terabyte to query data in BigQuery - it seems you ran out of it.

But don't worry! It replenishes on an ongoing basis, so you only need to wait a couple hours, not a full month to continue querying.

This query is only 33GB big, so you can do around 30 of these queries for free every month.

As you are only looking at 2015, a way to save quota is to use the monthly tables that the TLC provided, if you change the query to only July 2015:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(pickup_datetime) dayofweek, INTEGER(100*AVG(trip_distance/((dropoff_datetime-pickup_datetime)/3600000000)))/100 speed, 
FROM [nyc-tlc:yellow.trips_2015_07]
WHERE fare_amount/trip_distance between 2 and 10 
AND year(pickup_datetime) = 2015 
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1
```

This one only processes 353MB, so you could run 2,800 free queries like this a month (way better!).

Comment: I need to use the first half of 2015. And those records are only in the trips table.

Comment: Can you join the first 6 months together to get "the first half of 2015"? This will be less data than the full trips table, allowing you more queries within the free trial limit.